# Hausdorff distance property

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> **Question:** The *Hausdorff distance* between two nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ in a metric space $(X, \rho)$ is defined by
> $$
> d_H(A,B):=\max\left\{\sup_{x\in A}\operatorname{dist}(x,B),\sup_{y\in B}\operatorname{dist}(A,y)\right\}.
> $$
> Show that $d_H(A,B)=0$ if and only if $\operatorname{cl}(A)=\operatorname{cl}(B)$.

I know that for a subset $E$ of $X$, $\{x\in X:\operatorname{dist}(x,E)=0\}=\operatorname{cl}(E)$. Therefore, it's enough to show that $d_H(A,B)=0$ if and only if
$\{x\in X:\operatorname{dist}(x,A)=0\}=\{x\in X:\operatorname{dist}(x,B)=0\}$.

Firstly, suppose that $d_H(A,B)=0$. Then it must be that
$$
\sup_{x\in A}\operatorname{dist}(x,B)=0\implies\operatorname{dist}(x,B)=0,\text{ for every } x\in A
$$
and
$$
\sup_{y\in B}\operatorname{dist}(A,y)=0\implies\operatorname{dist}(A,y)=0,\text{ for every } y\in B.
$$
As such we have $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(B)$ and $B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A)$.

By definition, the closure is the smallest closed set containing the set so
$$
A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(B)
$$
and
$$
B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A).
$$
Therefore $\operatorname{cl}(A)=\operatorname{cl}(B)$.

Now, suppose $\operatorname{cl}(A)=\operatorname{cl}(B)$, or rather $\{x\in X:\operatorname{dist}(x,A)=0\}=\{x\in X:\operatorname{dist}(x,B)=0\}$. And this is where I get stuck for this direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\operatorname{cl}(A)=\operatorname{cl}(B)$. Then if $x \in A$, $x \in \operatorname{cl}(B)$ so $d(x,B)=0$. As this holds for all $x \in A$, $\sup_{x \in A} d(x,B)=0$. Symmetrically, $\sup_{y \in B} d(y,A)=0$ as well, and so their maximum $d_H(A,B)=0$ as well. I see no difficulty.

Comment: You're right, no difficulty...I was just looking at it wrong. Though, does the other direction look correct?

Comment: @D.Math Yes, that seems fine. The observation that $d(x,A)=0$ iff $x \in \operatorname{cl}(A)$ is the key.

Comment: I agree. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Hi Henno, perhaps you can help me with this related question--I'm sure you're well aware that if you take $d_H$ and restrict it to the compact subsets of $X$, denoted $\mathcal{K}(X)$, then $d_H$ is a metric. One property of being a metric is for $A,B\in\mathcal{K}(X)$: $d_H(A,B)=0$ iff $A=B$. To prove this, can the result I (and yourself) just proved be used?

Comment: @D.Math it’s an immediate corollary because compact sets are closed.

Comment: Compact sets being closed...how? This isn't obvious to me.

Comment: @D.Math it’s a standard fact certainly in metric spaces. So then $A=\operatorname{cl}(A)$ and equal closures means equal sets.

Comment: Well, isn't the point to prove it's a metric space? So one shouldn't assume it's a metric space and use that property, right?

Comment: The sets $A$ are in a metric space. That’s enough @D.Math

Comment: Oh, so they're closed with respect to the metric $\rho$, say $\operatorname{cl}_{\rho}(A)=A$?

Comment: @D.Math yes they are.

Comment: Got it, thanks!